# Visual Studio 2015 does not break on assert in gtest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, assert, googletest

When I debug a normal application and `assert()` happens, I get the usual error window which allows me to stop execution and analyze call stack, local variables etc, which is very convenient:

[image: assert]

However when I am running a Google Test unit test, assertions never trigger the debugger. Instead I get this error text in cmd window:

```
Assertion failed: indexMap.size() == points.size(), file test.cpp, line 220
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Which is not nearly as helpful. I am pretty sure gtest messes up asserts somehow and prevents creation of the error window. Is there a way to have traditional assert behavior when I'm running unit tests?

Comment: Are you sure this gtest unit was linked with debug version of CRT?

Comment: In the project settings it says: `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)`. Just like the project where asserts work. Also in gtest CMake file I found this option: `-Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON`

Comment: @MuertoExcobito thank you, this is what I was looking for! There is a note about this in documentation, but I somehow missed it: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/V1_7_AdvancedGuide.md#turning-assertion-failures-into-break-points
If there was also a way to make this a default behavior for CMake project (e.g. set define instead of command line option). But this is already great.